# How to count objects using tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

i want to count detected objects based on detection scores. I am using EdjeElectronics's Object detection code. And here's the code i've been using:

```
# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
```

This is the detection lines:

```
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
```

And visualizing it using this:

```
# Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.60)
```

My problem is, i found a video and that video tells me how to count based on scores (value of confidence). But i can't quite figure it out.

The guy in the video using this loop to count the detected objects:

```
# Loop over all detections and draw detection box if confidence is above minimum threshold
    for i in range (len(scores)):
        if ((scores[i] > 0.6).all() and (scores[i] <= 1.0).all()):

            current_count+=1
```

And print it on screen using this:

```
# Draw framerate, current count, and total count in corner of frame
    cv2.putText (frame,'Detections In Frame: ' + str(current_count),(30,75),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(98,189,184),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

So far, i can't update the `current_count` value, i'm guessing there's something wrong in the loop. So, i can't count the detected objects because it always showed `0` value. Please help me

Comment: Maybe none of your results are above the threshold? Have you printed the scores?

Comment: When it detect objects, the detected objects show 90% confidence. Either i'm using wrong variable at loop or i don't know...

Comment: I think the scores come in 2D, have you looked at the shape? `len(detection_scores)` might return 1

Comment: i'll try... sorry i'm new on this

Comment: TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. (detection_scores:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for shape information.

it give me error like this

Comment: When you call this function, `vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array`, what is `frame` that is being passed as the first argument? Is it an image?

Comment: a live video stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for box,score,cls in zip(boxes[0],scores[0],classes[0]):
    if score >= 0.6 and score <= 1.0:
        count += 1
```

Comment: omg, it worked... thank you so much.... but, can you explain what this line do :
for box,score,cls in zip(boxes[0],scores[0],classes[0]) ?
again, thank you so much

Comment: `boxes` basically are the bounding boxes that give you the value of the bounding box coordinates for the object. `classes` are integers that represents the class. You can check the corresponding class [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt). And finally `scores` represents the prediction scores by the model for the objects. The `[0]` is just used for indexing  
Each value, `box,score,cls` is for one object. You can try printing them out and having a look

Comment: okay... i tried and it worked... what about zip ? what is that ? and is this loop is looping from 0 to 1 for every value ? (boxes, scores, classes)

Comment: Zip allows you to loop through multiple lists at the same time. Here you are looping through three lists, boxes, classes and scores. I am afraid I didn’t understand your second question?  Each time we loop through, we get the box coordinates, class and detection score for one object that is represented by box, cls,score respectively

Comment: okay okay... i understand... thank you for your explanation...